# Imperial & Metric Proportional Editing Behaviour

Tags: units, proportional-editing

Does anyone know why the proportional editing values are dependent on the scene units, such that you have to enter different values to get the same result? See attached. As 1.21ft = 0.369m I'm guessing the proportional editing value remains metric regardless of the scene units, but I'm wondering if there's a reason for this, and if there's a way to override it?

[image]

[image]

I've reset the factory defaults and tried again. Still same issue.

This is what I'm doing.

New file
Press 'a' to select all then 'x' to delete
Add default mesh circle ( circle dimension 2m - no transform applied )
Press '7' ( top view )
Press '.' to zoom
Press TAB for edit mode
Select two vertices as shown
Enable proportional editing
Press 's' for scale
This presents me with this screen ( note the size of white proportional editing circle ) :

[image]

If I follow the exact same process but set the units to imperial first, the circle dimension is 2ft and I see this :

[image]

At first I thought the proportional editing wasn't working. I have to scroll out to see the white proportional editing circle :

[image]

Comment: Hello :). I really really tried, but I just cannot replicate such behavior. *Proportional Edit* is relative, not absolute, so unit system plays no role. Even switching units during transform yields correct results.

Comment: Hi Jachym - thank you for taking the time to investigate this. I figured it should be relative - no idea why this is happening. I've just reset to factory defaults and tried again. Still having the same problem. I'll update with more details of exactly what I'm doing in case I've over looked something simple.